# ping returns a different address before ssh into a device connected to a school network

Tags: networking, ssh, ping, ip-address

Currently I have a few Raspberry Pis connected to my university's protected network `Uni-PROTECTED`. When I am working on my laptop in the same room under the same network, I have no problem sshing into those Pis by using the IP addresses returned from `hostname -I`, e.g. `100.91.145.6`.

I want to work from home but I couldn't ssh since `100.91.145.6` is a private IP address. I have looked around on the internet which told me that I need to config the router. But since the router is managed by the building, I don't have access to it.

A solution I found is:
I tried to ping `100.91.145.6`, but it returns a different IP address `169.228.83.196`. And here is what `arp -a` returns after the ping:

```
b-wrlss-2t-6509-vlan999-gw.ucsd.edu (169.228.184.1) at 0:21:56:4a:38:0 on en0 permanent [ethernet]
? (224.0.0.251) at 1:0:5e:0:0:fb on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
? (239.255.255.250) at 1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
```

I can successfully ssh through `169.228.83.196` but now I am very confused by the three IP addresses. I am certain that `100.91.145.6` does not work with ssh because it is a private IP, but why pinging it returns a different one, and what is `169.228.145.6`?

Comment: Are you somehow connected to the campus network, possibly via VPN, when you ping 100.91.145.6 and get back 169.228.83.196? It seems like your school is running a "Carrier-Grade NAT" (CGNAT), and when you ping 100.91.145.6, you're getting back the publicly-routable IP address that the CGNAT has it mapped to. But I can't explain how your pings could have gotten to the right place unless you were somehow attached to the university's network.

Comment: Yes I was using a VPN of school.